# Excluding a folder in a recursive copy in Batch

Tags: batch-file, recursion, copy, xcopy

Basically what's going on is that we are migrating about 50 desktops from XP to 7.  I cannot install any extra programs to complete this task.  What I am doing is writing a script that copies the Desktop, Favourites, and My Documents, along with a few specific file types from the originating machine to a shared drive for the user.  Which later will be able to have all files moved to the new machine they are getting.  I'm trying to recursively search through Windows and get all .pst files and other files you will see in the script, and back them up to a folder on the share (but not in a directory structure, I just want all the files in a single directory no matter where they originated from) with the exception of My Documents.  Anything they have put in My Documents should be excluded in the search.  Anyway, this is what I started with:

```
@echo off
cls
set USRDIR=
set SHARE=
set /P USRDIR=Enter Local User Directory:  
set /p SHARE=Enter Shared Drive Name:  

set UPATH="c:\Documents and Settings\%USRDIR%"
set SPATH="g:\!MIGRATION"

set ESRI="%UPATH%\Application Data\ESRI"

net use g: /delete
net use g: \\server\%SHARE%
md %SPATH% %SPATH%\GIS %SPATH%\Outlook %SPATH%\Desktop %SPATH%\Documents %SPATH%\Favorites
if exists %ESRI% md %SPATH%\ESRI
md %SPATH%\misc %SPATH%\misc\GISfiles %SPATH%\misc\XMLfiles %SPATH%\misc\CSVfiles

for /R %%x in (*.mxd) do copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\GIS\"
for /R %%x in (*.dbf) do copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\GISfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.xml) do copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\XMLfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.csv) do copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\CSVfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.pst) do copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\Outlook\"
if exist %ESRI% xcopy /y /d /s /i /z %ESRI% %SPATH%\ESRI && echo ESRI YES || ESRI NO
xcopy /y /d /s /i /z "%UPATH%\Desktop" "%SPATH%\Desktop" && echo DESK YES || DESK NO
xcopy /y /d /s /i /z "%UPATH%\My Documents" "%SPATH%\Documents" && echo DOCS YES || DOCS NO
xcopy /y /d /s /i /z "%UPATH%\Favorites" "%SPATH%\Favorites" && echo FAVS YES || FAVS NO

echo "Script Complete!"
pause
```

I then decided that I wanted to exclude My Documents just in case so I don't end up with a bunch of duplicates where anything they put in My Documents ends up getting copied twice.  So I changed that recursive block to this:

```
for /R %%x in (*.mxd) do xcopy /y /d /z /exclude:"\My Documents\" "%%x" "%SPATH%\GIS\"
for /R %%x in (*.dbf) do xcopy /y /d /z /exclude:"\My Documents\" "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\GISfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.xml) do xcopy /y /d /z /exclude:"\My Documents\" "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\XMLfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.csv) do xcopy /y /d /z /exclude:"\My Documents\" "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\CSVfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.pst) do xcopy /y /d /z /exclude:"\My Documents\" "%%x" "%SPATH%\Outlook\"
```

Anyway, my question is this, is this the most efficient way of doing this?  Is there a better way?  I'm curious because I have no one here to bounce ideas or anything off of, I'm the sole on site support here.  If someone sees a better way or thinks this is how they would do it, please let me know.  There are a bunch more filetypes in there, but I removed most of them so the code sample wasn't so long, left enough to get the point across.

**EDIT:  Just to make it clear, I am not the IT Department for this organization.  I'm a technical support liaison for the department to a separate IT division.  Our actual IT department calls this a migration, but it's more or less a simple "lets in stall new machines without doing anything to prepare for it" sort of soup sandwich operation.  I can't install, remove, or change the systems in any way, I can only backup the files.**

Comment: I can help in a few hours in case no-one answers.

Comment: that would be great, im off in half an hour, but in the morning i will be using this and at the point will be able to test any suggestions and mark an answer.

Comment: actually, this looks pretty good. too bad each file type need a different destination folder or you could do then all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the best option is reduce processing in batch files to the minimum, leaving as much as possible to commands. But if you have to iterate over the file system several times, it is better to do only one pass and process in batch.

Adapted from a more general batch. I have made changes to adjust to what you need, but somethings more specific (your ESRI folder) are not added. Adapt as needed.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Ask for share name
    set /P share=Enter Shared drive name:
    if "%share%"=="" (
        call :error "No share name provided"
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem Configure target of copy
    set target=g:

    rem Connect to target
    net use %target% /delete 
    net use %target% \\server\%share%

    if not exist %target% (
        call :error "No connection to server"
        goto endProcess
    )   

    rem Configure directory by extension
    set extensions=.mxd .dbf .xml .csv .pst
    set .mxd=GIS
    set .dbf=misc\GISFiles
    set .xml=misc\XMLFiles
    set .csv=misc\CSVFiles
    set .pst=Outlook

    rem adjust target of copy to user name
    set target=%target%\!MIGRATION\%username%
    if not exist "%target%" (
        mkdir "%target%"
    )

    rem Configure source of copy
    set source=%userprofile%
    if not exist "%source%" (
        call :error "User profile directory not found"
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem Resolve My Documents folder
    call :getShellFolder Personal
    set myDocPath=%shellFolder%

    if not exist "%myDocPath%" (
        call :error "My Documents directory not found"
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem Ensure target directories exists
    mkdir "%target%" > nul 2>nul
    for %%e in ( %extensions% ) do mkdir "%target%\!%%e!" >nul 2>nul

    rem We are going to filter file list using findstr. Generate temp file
    rem with strings, just to ensure final command line is in limits
    rem This will contain not desired folders/files or anything that will be
    rem copied later

    set filterFile="%temp%\filter.temp"
    (
        echo %myDocPath%
        echo \Temporary Internet Files\
        echo \Temp\
    ) > %filterFile%

    rem Process user profile, excluding My Documents, IE Temp and not needed extensions
    for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%source%" ^| findstr /v /i /g:%filterFile% ^| findstr /i /e "%extensions%" ') do (
        call :processFile "%%~xf" "%%f"
    )

    rem Now, process "especial" folders

    mkdir "%target%\Documents"
    xcopy /y /d /s /i /z "%myDocPath%" "%target%\Documents"

    call :getShellFolder Desktop
    if exist "%shellFolder%" (
        mkdir "%target%\Desktop"
        xcopy /y /d /s /i /z "%shellFolder%" "%target%\Desktop"
        if errorlevel 1 (
            call :error "Failed to copy desktop files"
        )
    )

    call :getShellFolder Favorites
    if exist "%shellFolder%" (
        mkdir "%target%\Favorites"
        xcopy /y /d /s /i /z "%shellFolder%" "%target%\Favorites"
        if errorlevel 1 (
            call :error "Failed to copy favorites"
        )
    )

    rem Finish
    goto :endProcess

rem ** subroutines *******************************************

:processFile
    rem retrieve parameters 
    rem : %1 = file extension
    rem : %2 = file 
    set ext=%~1
    set file=%~2

    rem manage .something files
    if "%ext%"=="%file%" (
        set file=%ext%
        set ext=
    )

    rem manage no extension files
    if "%ext%"=="" (
        rem WILL NOT COPY
        goto :EOF
    )

    rem determine target directory based on file extension
    set extCmd=%%%ext%%%
    for /F "tokens=*" %%d in ('echo %extCmd%^|find /v "%%" ' ) do set folder=%%d

    if "%folder%"=="" (
        rem file extension not in copy list
        goto :EOF
    )

    copy /y /z "%file%" "%target%\%folder%" >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        call :error "Failed to copy [%file%]"
    ) else (
        echo %file%
    )

    goto :EOF

:getShellFolder
    set _sf=%~1
    set shellFolder=
    if "%_sf%"=="" goto :EOF
    for /F "tokens=2,*" %%# in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "%_sf%" ^| find "%_sf%"') do (
        set shellFolder=%%$
    )
    goto :EOF


:error
    echo.
    echo ERROR : %~1
    echo.
    goto :EOF   


:endProcess

    endlocal
    exit /b
```

Comment: This looks sound with one exception, it's breaking down with finding the My Documents directory within the getShellFolder subroutine, the space in Documents and Settings is causing the variable to be defined as "C:\Documents" and ending the variable at the space.  Any ideas on how to fix that?  Where you have quotes are correct, except  the part where the 3rd token is ending at the space rather than the end of the Data Field in the Registry

Comment: Sorry. Copied and pasted from where it shouldn't as it shouldn't. Corrected in answer.

Comment: running into a new problem, I tried to add /exclude:"\My Music\" to the xcopy that moves the My Documents directory, but now it wont copy anything out of that directory at all.  outside that, everything is working perfectly

Comment: Well, according to documentation, /exclude accepts a file name not a string. Inside this file, each line contains a string to check against the file list to select what to exclude.

Comment: It also says though that if you put "\folder name\" it will exclude a folder.  I found a workaround, I just moved the folder to the temp dir and them moved it back when finished

Comment: According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx), the only valid way of indicating a string to match in exclusion, is to put the string into a file. A good explanation is [here](http://commandwindows.com/xcopy.htm?ModPagespeed=noscript)

Answer (score 1):

Try [User State Migration Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_State_Migration_Tool) from Microsoft - I used it to move around 400 systems in less than 30 days. It takes a bit of setup for the script to run right, but it does a really really good job (and no program to install).

In default mode, it gets all PST files, Document, Desktop, Favorites, and a ton of other folders/registry settings. It also does this for all users on a computer (which can be limited by last login date or number of profiles) as long as the user running it is a local admin.

It may or may not work for what you need, but it's a good choice when designing a migration. It sounds like what you are trying to do can be done with USMT just by removing extra code in the ini files.

Comment: I can't.  The IT Department is full of idiots who are not actually migrating anything.  They expect the end user to back up everything themselves.  This is why I'm doing this, to try to make the process less painful on the less savy people in the organization.  I have no control over the computers, I cannot do anything other than copy the files.

Comment: Alternatively you can let them make the change, then complain non-stop until they fix it. I work in an IT department - If they don't migrate at least the basic stuff, they aren't doing their jobs. That being said, this is just a program that you run (no boot disks, can run without admin rights just for the current user). Worth a serious look. I did this for a large auto maker around 8 years ago, without admin rights, and it worked pretty darn well.

Comment: LOL.  Yeah these new machines have the UAC where I'm no longer a local admin.  So every little change that needs to be done to the computer will now have to go through IT.  I plan on flooding the help desk with requests until they figure out they need to let me have an admin account to deal with Win7 Machines.  These clowns really are something else though, it's the most inept IT department I've dealt with in the Government Sector.

Comment: The easiest way I can say to do this is to create a batch file that moves everything in their main folders (Documents, Desktop...) to a network share. I would bring this up to your management, as this limits you to an option they don't like (using tons of NAS storage, depending on file size, or network utilization). Again, bad IT staff if they don't move what you need. I hate doing manual migrations, but I still move whatever they need manually so they can do their jobs.

Comment: Well, I am moving those user folders.  If you look at the script you will see that My documents, favourites, and desktop all get backed up.  The problem is that if they have the file twice on the computer (say random folders here and there that are outside the normal places) that I catch those but don't have duplicates.  I want to make sure that the My Documents folder is ignored when searching through the rest of the computer to back up stragglers that didn't get moved to Documents by the user.

Answer (score 0):

This checks and excludes any folder that ends with `documents\` (or includes it, so subdirectories too) as IIRC the folder may be called `\documents\` or `\my documents\` and is case insensitive.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%x in (*.mxd) do set "check=%%~dpx" & if /i "!check!"=="!check:documents\=!" copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\GIS\"
for /R %%x in (*.dbf) do set "check=%%~dpx" & if /i "!check!"=="!check:documents\=!" copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\GISfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.xml) do set "check=%%~dpx" & if /i "!check!"=="!check:documents\=!" copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\XMLfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.csv) do set "check=%%~dpx" & if /i "!check!"=="!check:documents\=!" copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\misc\CSVfiles\"
for /R %%x in (*.pst) do set "check=%%~dpx" & if /i "!check!"=="!check:documents\=!" copy "%%x" "%SPATH%\Outlook\"
endlocal
```